# Getting Facebook page name on like event

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, dom-events, facebook-like

I have multiple Facebook like boxes in one page.

Suppose, I have two dives that contain

```
<div class="some">
Facebook like widget,
<input name="test_1" value="1" />
</div>

<div class="some">
Facebook like widget,
<input name="test_2" value="2" />
</div>
```

So when a user likes one of the page, I can capture like event using `FB.event`.

**The problem is when a page like event occurs, I want to get
 corresponding `input:value`**

For example user likes first button I want:

> test_1 value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I assign an id to my input element like this

```
<input id="test_<?= $fb_id;?>" value="1" />
```

and then in `FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, response) {`

I accessed element like this

```
var r = href.split('/');
document.getElementById("test_"+r[3]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you catch the like event, the response contains the URL liked.

You should be able to get the desired information that way.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but I have already done this successfully.
:)